# How to concatenate string in JSTL within a forEach loop?

Tags: string, jstl

The following code in JSP Scriptlet works exactly that I need (using Spring/Hibernet).

```
<%

org.hibernate.Session s=NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
s.beginTransaction();

java.util.List<model.Movies> m=s.createQuery("from model.Movies order by moviesId").list();

for(model.Movies row:m)
{
    String id="";
    for(model.Language lan:row.getLanguages())
    {
        id+=lan.getLanguageId()+",";
    }
    out.println(id);
}

s.flush();
s.getTransaction().commit();

%>
```

It displays movie `langiageId` for each movie in the database (One movie has many languages). it concatenates `languageId` separated by commas for each movie. For instance, if the first movie has 3 languageId, it displays 1,2,3. If the second movie (row in the database) has 4 languages, it displays 4,5,6,7 in the next line and so on. How can the same thing be possible with JSTL? The following is the incomplete version of JSTL `forEach` loop that I didn't figure out.

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="row" varStatus="status">
    <c:forEach items="${row.languages}" var="lan" varStatus="status">
        <c:set value="${lan.languageId}" scope="request" var="id">

        </c:set>

    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

How can I get `languageId` separated by commas for each group of movies separately? When the inner `forEach` completes, the `id` should be reinitialized to an empty string such as the one shown in the Scriptlet.

Comment: I'd wrap this up in a custom tag or function; that's a lot of noise just to create a comma-separated list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
<c:set value="${id}${status.first ? '' : ','}${lan.languageId}" scope="request" var="id" />
```

Comment: It worked for me. I also have alternatively used a *custom tag* to achieve the same. Thanks.